# Creating an interface or abstract that forces you to implement a method that returns this called class in C#

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

I'm trying to create a sort of a ServiceManager in C#.

I want it to have a set and a get function.

The set signature looks like this:

`public void set(string key, ServiceProvider service)`

`public ServiceProvider get(string key)`

I am not sure how write `class ServiceProvider`

I want it to include a `create` method that returns itself

For example:

```
public class SomeService : ServiceProvider
{
    public static SomeService create(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        return new SomeService();
    }
}
```

Another Example:

```
public class SomeOtherService : ServiceProvider
{
    protected FooService fooService;

    public SomeOtherService(FooService fooService)
    {
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    public static SomeOtherService create(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        return new SomeOtherService (serviceManager.get("FooService"));
    }
}
```

How do I implement `ServiceProvider` to force me into writing that create method?

EDIT1:
I wanted to explain why I need to build it that way.
The idea is to make the get method **lazy** so when I call it by its name, only then I start the instance and save it as a singleton in the ServiceManager.

EDIT2:
The idea behind this is that every class that implements/inherits from `ServiceProvider` can implement create as he wishes.

For example:
`PlayerService` needs to have a database adapter in its constructor.

`UtilService` has no parameters in its constructor.

Behind the scenes...
When `ServiceManager.get(key)` is called, it checks a **dictionary** for the instance, and if it does not exist, it creates it using the `create()` method and assign it to the dictionary and returns it.

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
namespace Infrastructure.Base.Service
{
    public class ServiceManager : Contracts.IServiceManager
    {
        Dictionary<Type, Contracts.IServiceProvider> dictonary;

        public ServiceManager()
        {
            dictonary = new Dictionary<Type, Contracts.IServiceProvider>();
        }

        public Contracts.IServiceProvider get<T>() where T : Contracts.IServiceProvider
        {
            if (!dictonary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                var service = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this);
                dictonary[typeof(T)] = service;
            } 

            return dictonary[typeof(T)];
        }
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.Base.Service.Contracts
{
    public interface IServiceProvider
    {
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.Base.Service.Contracts
{
    public interface IServiceManager
    {
        Infrastructure.Base.Service.Contracts.IServiceProvider get<T>() where T : Infrastructure.Base.Service.Contracts.IServiceProvider;
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
public class PlayerService : IServiceProvider
{
    PlayerAdapter playerAdapter;

    public PlayerService(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        playerAdapter = serviceManager.get<PlayerAdapter>() as PlayerAdapter;
        Debug.Log("I am player service!");
    }
}

public class PlayerAdapter : IServiceProvider
{
    public PlayerAdapter(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
        Debug.Log(" I am PlayerAdapter!");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    serviceManager = new ServiceManager();
    PlayerService playerService = serviceManager.get<PlayerService>() as PlayerService;
}
```

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to make a second constructor. Why not use simply the constructor with `new SomeService()` ? One of the problems with your example is that you want to have it `static`. You could force `SomeService` to implement the inherited `create()` method if you would declare it as `abstract` in `ServiceProvider`, but that would not allow you be that method `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not override a static method in C#. Static and Virtual are exlusive terms in the language.

What you seem to need is a simple repository:

```
public abstract class ServiceProvider
{

}

public class ServiceManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, ServiceProvider> repository;

    public ServiceManager()
    {
        repository = new Dictionary<Type, ServiceProvider>();
    }

    public ServiceProvider Get<T>() where T : ServiceProvider
    {
        if (repository.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            return repository[typeof(T)];

        var service = (T)Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        repository[typeof(T)] = service;
        return service;
    }
}
```

Now implement your concrete service providers:

```
public class MyServiceFoo : ServiceProvider
{
    public MyServiceFoo()
    { /*construction logic (your Create()) goes here*/ }
}

public class MyServiceBlah : ServiceProvider
{
    public MyServiceBlah()
    { /*construction logic (your Create()) goes here*/ }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var manager = new ServiceManager();
var myFooProvider = manager.Get<MyServiceFoo>();
var myOtherFooProvider = manager.Get<MyServiceFoo>();

var areTheSame = ReferenceEquals(myFooProvider, myOtherFooProvider); //returns true
```

**UPDATE**

If some of the service providers need arguments when creating them, then simply change the `Get` method to the following:

```
public ServiceProvider Get<T>(params object[] args) where T : ServiceProvider
{
    if (repository.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        return repository[typeof(T)];

    var service = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    repository[typeof(T)] = service;
    return service;
}
```

And now, considering you have the following service:

```
public class MyServiceBar : ServiceProvider
{
    public MyServiceBar(int myInt)
    { /*construction logic (your Create()) goes here*/ }
}
```

You'd simply do:

```
var manager = new ServiceManager();
var myFooProvider = manager.Get<MyServiceFoo>();
var myServiceBar= manager.Get<MyServiceBar>(1);
```

Comment: This would be perfect if it allowed me to implement different constructors with different parameter. Take a look a the 2nd example.

Comment: Passing the needed params in the get is not what I was reffering to.
Think more about what happens if your FooService needs to get BarService in his Constructor and save it as one of its attributes. Again please look at the 2nd example it should clear it up.

Comment: Perhaps I should add the ServiceManager a lazy factory, do you know how can it be done?

Comment: I've decided to create a constructor that has a ServiceManager in it and it will be used to populate the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this for the base class

```
public abstract class ServiceProvider<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

and then you don't even need implement `Create` in the derived class

```
public class SomeService : ServiceProvider<SomeService>
{
}
```

Comment: I edited.
The problem with this is it will not let me override create, and it is something that I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is now way to force implementing static method. You will have to take care of this by yourself.
Other way is that you make your class generic and inside this class you have static create method that creates deriving object:

```
public class ServiceProvider<T>
{
    public static T Create()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited.
The problem with this is it will not let me override create, and it is something that I need to do.

Comment: @Mong Zhu I forgot to add <T> on ServiceProvider class

Comment: @JacobCohen You cannot cannot override static method. So you can have different constructor for every class, and this static generic method in base class call constructors of this derived classes

Comment: @Kodre
Perhaps don't stick to my syntanx, any ideas of how to implement my concept?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you arise is common in software development, but the solution your trying to implement is not a best practice.

I suggest to use an **IOC** (inversion of control container) like Unity.

With it you can configure almost everything about your object lifetime (for example you can specify if you need a new object or using a single instance, and so on).

You shouldn't write code if someone (Unity) does it for you.

*Don't follow solutions that involve reflection*: in my opinion reflection is the last solution to a problem; it happens at runtime so you could be surprised by runtime errors, it isn't a light operation, and you loss every compile time benefit.

*Don't use singleton*: it's an antipattern because it mix up 2 responsabilites (object creation and object lifetime management) and introduce testing problems.

With an IOC you can manage the lifetime of your object (create it, when you want it, if you want single instance) and have all benefit of testability.

Comment: This is actually my attempt to implement a IOC using a ServiceManager.

The idea is to pass it on to my controllers and thus have a nice DI.